# deleting a dataframe row by MultiIndex value

Tags: pandas, indexing, multi-index

From a `DataFrame` with a `MultiIndex`  of boolean combinations, I want to delete the row for which none of the index values are True:

```
T000001 T000025 
True    False   1430.0
False   True    301.0
False   False   7950.0
```

Treating the index entries as boolean arrays does not work:

```
df[~df.index.any()]



TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-caeaa0a17799> in <module>
----> 1 combi.index.any()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in invalid_op(self, other)
    212     def invalid_op(self, other=None):
    213         raise TypeError("cannot perform {name} with this index type: "
--> 214                         "{typ}".format(name=name, typ=type(self).__name__))
    215 
    216     invalid_op.__name__ = name

TypeError: cannot perform any with this index type: MultiIndex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `MultiIndex` to `DataFrame` by [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html), remove inverting `~` and check `any` per rows by `axis=1`:

```
df = df[df.index.to_frame().any(axis=1)]
print (df)
T000001  T000025
True     False      1430.0
False    True        301.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```